# Why does Tkinter.TopLevel.wm_geometry() return "1x1+0+0"?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a Tkinter root window and a tk.Toplevel.  When I call `.wm_geometry()` on the root window and on the Toplevel, they both return the string `1x1+0+0`, even when my windows are visible on the screen.

A condensed version of my code is:

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
window = tk.Toplevel(root)
window.withdraw()
# add things to this window
root.after(0, execute_next_instruction)
root.mainloop()

def execute_next_instruction():  
    window.wm_geometry()  # "1x1+0+0"
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't tell me anything"? It tells you the x,y coordinate of the upper left part of the window, and it tells you the window width and height.

Comment: My window is not at the coordinates 1,1 and my window does not have dimensions of 0,0.

Comment: Are you calling the command before starting `mainloop` and/or calling `update()`? It won't have a size or position until it is actually mapped to the screen. Can you include an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: It turned out that the issue was calling `wm_geometry` too quickly after `deiconify()` was called.

Comment: "The geometry is not accurate until the application has updated its idle tasks. In particular, all geometries are initially '1x1+0+0' until the widgets and geometry manager have negotiated their sizes and positions. See the .update_idletasks() method, above, in this section to see how to insure that the widget's geometry is up to date."

https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/universal.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that because I was using `tk.Tk.after(0, execute_next_instruction)`, the calls to get the window geometry information were still executing before the window was ready.  The fix was to use `tk.Tk.after(1, execute_next_instruction)`.

Comment: Yes, `after(0,...)` should be used very sparringly, if at all.

Answer (score -1):

Pass in the position using `wm_geometry()`. When called with no arguments it returns the current geometry (width x height + x-position + y position). You also call it on the window instance. eg:

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.wm_geometry("800x600+0+0")
# ... other stuff ...
root.mainloop()
```