# Tkinter size of root, canvas and rectangle

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new to stack overflow (first post) and Tkinter and I'm trying to reproduce a graphical environment that was provided by my CS teacher on an online virtual machine, in order to test my projects on my actual computer and avoid long testing times (and I thought it could be interesting to do).

I'm running into an issue with widget dimensions:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas
from math import *


def initialize(width, height, title="", root = Tk()):
    root.geometry(str(width)+"x"+str(height))
    canvas = Canvas(root, background="white")
    canvas.place(relheight = 1.0, relwidth = 1.0)
    return {"width" : width, "height" : height, "title" : title, "root" : root, "canvas" : canvas}


def create_rectangle(top_corner, width, height, color):
    return {"top_corner" : top_corner, "width" : width, "height" : height, "color" : color}


def draw_rectangle(rectangle, canvas):
    top_corner, width, height, color = rectangle["top_corner"], rectangle["width"], rectangle["height"], rectangle["color"]
    #converting from (r,g,b) to hex
    coloring = '#%02x%02x%02x' % color
    canvas.create_rectangle(top_corner, (top_corner[0] + width, top_corner[1] + height), width=1, fill=coloring, outline=coloring)
    canvas.grid()


def fill_window(color, window):
    r = create_rectangle((0,0), window["width"], window["height"], color)
    print(r)
    draw_rectangle(r, window["canvas"])

def main():
    window = initialize(600, 600)
    print(window)
    fill_window((100,30,26), window)
    print(window["root"].winfo_width(), window["root"].winfo_height())
    print(window["canvas"].winfo_width(), window["canvas"].winfo_height())
    print(window["root"].winfo_reqwidth(), window["root"].winfo_reqheight())
    print(window["canvas"].winfo_reqwidth(), window["canvas"].winfo_reqheight())
    window["root"].mainloop()


main()
```

which outputs :

```
{'width': 600, 'height': 600, 'title': '', 'root': <tkinter.Tk object .>, 'canvas': <tkinter.Canvas object .!canvas>}
{'top_corner': (0, 0), 'width': 600, 'height': 600, 'color': (100, 30, 26)}
1 1
1 1
200 200
289 204
```

I do not understand these values of winfo, and the rectangle which should the size of the window (I think it's actually the window which is bigger than 600x600)

I hope what I'm showing here is not too chaotic and would very much appreciate some help !

Thank you in advance

Comment: see how to produce a [mcve]

Comment: also see https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm, this shows what values of winfo are

Comment: Please also frame your question title as a question

Answer (score 0):

> I do not understand these values of winfo…

These values aren't as one would expect just because you are querying them before the window has been *drawn* (which occurs asynchronously), i. e. when they are not yet finally set. If you wait a bit before querying, you'll see. Cf. [Why does Tkinter.TopLevel.wm_geometry() return “1x1+0+0”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33599536/why-does-tkinter-toplevel-wm-geometry-return-1x100)